# List of mathematical operations in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I've created a list of a mathematic expression such as `[1,+,2,-,3]` and I'm trying to get this evaluated as `1+2-3 i.e 0`. However, I'm having trouble implementing this.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
test(List, Atom) :-
    atomic_list_concat(List, '', Val),
    Atom is Val.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to get (1+2)-3 or 1+(2-3)? What about other operators are there any priorities you have to take into account (as in * always comes before +, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `atomic_list_concat` is that the result is a single atom, not a term. So Prolog doesn't know how to "execute" it using `is/2`.

You can convert the atom to a term using `term_to_atom/2`:

```
eval_exp(List, Result) :-
    atomic_list_concat(List, '', Atom),  % This relates a list to an atom
    term_to_atom(Term, Atom),            % This relates an atom to term
    Result is Term.                      % This evaluates a term
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should implement a parser which converts given list into syntax tree.

you should convert
    [1,+,2,-,3]
into
    -(+(1,2),3)

```
    ?- A is -(+(1,2),3).
    A = 0.
```

Parser is often developed by using DCG.
You may consider about operators priority(* is stronger than +) and which direction the tree extends
I.E.  you should decide

```
[a,+,b,+,c]
```

is converted into

+(a,+(b,c))

or

+(+(a,b),c)

I'm sorry for my bad English!